# Shouldn't there be "bogie" instead of "bogey" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, usage

I read a sentence in a chapter in my book which was:

> A bogey of a train that was returning from Ayodhya and was full of Karsevaks was set on fire.

I didn't find any dictionary describing the word "bogey" in the sense it has been used in here. So I want to know whether it is acceptable to use the word "bogey" as a variant of "bogie"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary lists ***bogy*** and ***bogey*** as alternative spellings for ***bogie*** (their "low-slung trolley / truck" entry, which is particularly common in rail contexts).

But they have another 4 separate entries for ***bogey*** (all with different meanings and etymologies), 3 of which explicitly include ***bogie*** as a valid alternative spelling.

---

In short, there's probably no point in a *learners'* site trying to lay down the law about "correct" spelling for any given use of these 5 words. Things are of course even further complicated by the fact that many of us would probably pluralise *all* of them as ***bogies***. [Here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bogey%2Cbogeys%2Cbogie%2Cbogies&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbogey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbogeys%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbogie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbogies%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbogey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbogeys%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbogie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbogies%3B%2Cc0) showing that although singular ***bogey*** is the overall most common spelling (way more so than ***bogie***), the plural ***bogeys*** is in fact the *least* common form.

Answer (score -1):

The two have completely different meanings and it seems "bogie" perfectly describes what you're referring to, so I don't know why you would use "bogey" in place of it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Bogie:

> 2a chiefly British : a swiveling railway truck

[Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bogie)

Example picture:
[image: Railway Truck - Bogie]